# Windows-11 File Sort Command to view all files within subfolders

Tags: windows-11, sorting

I used to use a sort command when trying to view all files across a bunch of folders at once. It makes sorting files easier. I do know part of the command was written as not sort kind, I may even have the word order off slightly however I am unable to remember which parts need to be capitalised, and where the colon (:) goes. I have trying googling the answer, and even gone through hours of YouTube videos trying to find the answer. I would prefer not to use the asterisk (*) command as that is not suitable for my use.

As an example I have tried:

```
not: SORT kind
NOT kind: sort
NOT :kind sort
NOT: kind sort
SORT: not KIND
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Search bar in Explorer, typing:

- `kind:NOT Folder`
  will display all the files in the folder and all its sub-folders. Then you can sort or group by `FolderPath`:

Unable to upload screenshots -- dialog rturning "Server Error"

If you want to search multiple locations, creaet a custom library containing the desired folders, right-click in the folder background and select:

- `Arrange by >` -> `Name`

Comment: Thank you! This does exactly what I need it to.